# Is there a way to insert a small Ruby script inside an Android application?

Tags: android, ruby, web-scraping

I have a ruby web scraper which i want to use on the go, inside an Android Application. Is it possible to do that or anything similar using which i can achieve this?

Any help appreciated.

PS - I don't want to create the app in ruby like Ruboto, i just want the script to run and output results in a pure native Android App.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the script need to run from the Android device, or can you simply have it run on a server which communicates with the Android device?

Comment: @EmmanuelBuckshi Thanks for the quick reply. And no there is no need for a server to run as the script is a very small one which just queries a single website and populates a list based on the input parameters, that's it.

Comment: Android does not have a Ruby interpreter. You would need to find a suitable interpreter, embed it and the script in your app, then teach your app to use the interpreter to run the script. It may be simpler to rewrite the Ruby script in Java.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah even i was beginning to think that its better to write the code in C++ or Java to skip all the hassle. But i'll like to find a way first. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @XavI agree with CommonsWare's assessment in that it would have to be written in Java (or C++). Alternatively, you could just setup a simple REST API to trigger the script off of a different device which can run Ruby scripts (a linux instance/droplet/etc), and then write an Android app which triggers the script and/or downloads updated data from it.